# Share bicep modules to other tenant

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have created a lot of bicep modules and have them published in Azure container registry. I am referring them in applications as private registries.

I have a situation where I want to make these available in a different tenant. I understand there are public registry but of Microsoft and can be contributed to by MS employees. Also while finding how to get this done I came across a solution using Azure lighthouse.

Are these the only two way possible as neither is feasible for me? Do we have any other way to share bicep modules sitting in an ACR in tenant A to be made available in tenant B?

Answer (score 1):

Using B2B (inviting a guest into your AAD tenant from another tenant) [does not work](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/10665) unfortunately. Work to [support token auth](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4947) is being planned, and when complete will fulfil your scenario.

The Azure Lighthouse method you mention, or replicating the module versions in multiple tenants will likely the best option for the time being.

The only other option available to you is to enable [unauthenticated pull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/anonymous-pull-access) on the registry.... Then not just tenant B could access, but anyone that found it

[image]

Comment: I am not sure inviting would work, we have done testing in our tenant's public subscription till client environment was getting ready. Now we have to use client tenant to deploy so we wanted to use the modules from the ACR we have in our tenant.

Comment: If you do come across something please share, I am trying out as well. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Thanks GordonBy, and it seems the support will be on premium acr

Comment: What will happen if I enable the existing service connection in use (in our tenant/sub) in the client's tenant?